# Problem with link to boost library, but boost library exists

Tags: c++, boost

I try to run a simulator (GPGPU-sim). However, when I make, there are errors with link to boost library. Below is part of the error code. Other error messages are similar to it.

```
    /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:425: error: undefined
reference to 'boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char,
boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*,
unsigned int)'
```

The make option is:

```
FLAGS = -ggdb -I${BOOST_ROOT} -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem
```

The {BOOST_ROOT} does not the directory. However, I checked the /usr/lib and libboost_regex.a and libboost_filesystem.a files actually exist.

Can you help me to figure it out?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Are there any other errors further up or down in the error messages that references boost_regex library at all?

Comment: If the files wouldn't be found you should get a different error.

Comment: Also, can you post the full g++ command that is run, how the arguments are ordered, etc?

Comment: Try with a different g++ version. I had this problem too and I solved it when I changed my g++ version from 4.6 to 4.4 alternative

Answer (score 0):

check that you have correct version of `libboost_regex.a`. just build it from sources that your compile with

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full command line that fails. From what your posted, it seems like the command line would have `-lboost_regex` before the list of object files. Try moving it after that list.